Is there a way to redirect the data and obb folder locations that an app uses?
I was thinking about a workaround for the locked down scoped storage that fully closes off access to the android/data and android/obb folders (on some devices) So my thought of a workaround that would fix this issue would be just not using thosse folders entirely, and somehow patching apps before installing them so they use a different location like example/data. There are systems like xposed that makes it possible to modify an apk. But sadly I havent found any xposed modules that can do such thing, so I would like to know if this would be possible or not.

Xposed only works on rooted devices and on rooted devices you don't have problems accessing any folder locations as you simply can make use of root permissions via su.

@Robert You can patch apks with lspatch or xpatch which to my knowledge doesnt require root.
